# How to give VSCode Flatpak package access to system SDK for Java?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, java, sandbox, flatpak

I have installed VSCode flatpak package.

```
flatpak install flathub com.visualstudio.code
```

Now there is a file `flatpak-warning.txt`

It reads

```
https://www.flathub.org

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Warning: You are running an unofficial Flatpak version of Visual Studio Code !!! |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Please open issues under: https://github.com/flathub/com.visualstudio.code/issues


This version is running inside a container and is therefore not able
to access SDKs on your host system!

To execute commands on the host system, run inside the sandbox:

  $ flatpak-spawn --host <COMMAND>
  
To make the Integrated Terminal automatically use the host system's shell,
you can add this to the settings:

  {
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "bash",
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
        "bash": {
          "path": "/usr/bin/flatpak-spawn",
          "args": ["--host", "--env=TERM=xterm-256color", "bash"]
        }
    }
  }

This flatpak provides a standard development environment (gcc, python, etc).
To see what's available:

  $ flatpak run --command=sh com.visualstudio.code
  $ ls /usr/bin (shared runtime)
  $ ls /app/bin (bundled with this flatpak)

To get support for additional languages, you have to install SDK extensions, e.g.

  $ flatpak install flathub org.freedesktop.Sdk.Extension.dotnet
  $ flatpak install flathub org.freedesktop.Sdk.Extension.golang
  $ FLATPAK_ENABLE_SDK_EXT=dotnet,golang flatpak run com.visualstudio.code

You can use

  $ flatpak search <TEXT>

to find others.
```

Now I have OpenJDK installed on system.

```
java --version
openjdk 11.0.13 2021-10-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+8-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.21.10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.13+8-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.21.10, mixed mode, sharing)
```

But when I try to create a Java Project it shows no build tools.

Now my question is I can't figure out where to add the lines -

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "bash",
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
        "bash": {
          "path": "/usr/bin/flatpak-spawn",
          "args": ["--host", "--env=TERM=xterm-256color", "bash"]
        }
    }
  }
```

Also I am unable to understand -

```
$ flatpak-spawn --host <COMMAND>
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if you're still looking for an answer, but here's what worked for me (not using the system SDK, but one that is made as a Flatpak extension):

1. Check the available Java SDK extensions for Flatpak (those can be accessed by VSCode): `flatpak search Sdk | grep -i jdk`:
   [jdk search output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSRo9.png)
2. Install the one(s) that you want, for example `flatpak install org.freedesktop.Sdk.Extension.openjdk17`
3. As instructed in the flatpak-warning.txt file, you can see what is available to your flatpaks (binaries, SDKs,...) by running the flatpak shell with the VSCode command `flatpak run --command=sh com.visualstudio.code`. The JDK extension installed in step 2 is kept in /usr/lib/sdk in the flatpak hierarchy (at least on my Fedora install, but I think it should be the same on Ubuntu). Confirm by running `ls /usr/lib/sdk` **in the flatpak shell** and you should see your SDK there (possibly among other things):
   [listed in /usr/lib/sdk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMiEM.png)
4. You need to add this to the VSCode configuration, for me it was in settings.json:

```
    "java.jdt.ls.java.home": "/usr/lib/sdk/openjdk17/jvm/openjdk-17.0.1/"`,
    "java.configuration.runtimes": [
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-17",
            "path": "/usr/lib/sdk/openjdk17/jvm/openjdk-17.0.1/",
            "default": true
        }
    ],
```

After this I restarted VSCode and everything worked.
BTW when anything that you have to do in the flatpak shell should work just the same in the terminal window of VSCode itself.

Comment: What if I use the open jdk available in ubuntu repository instead of the flatpak one?

Comment: This work great, but you have to be careful to choose the openjdk version that match the version of "Freedesktop SDK" (org.freedesktop.Sdk). To get the installed Freedesktop SDK installed, just run flatpak list --runtime and look for the line (or grep it).

Answer (score 0):

You can add those lines in settings.json file.

and as mentioned in flatpak-warning.txt run the host command inside sandbox
eg:

> flatpak-spawn --host java --version

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I am using Linux Mint 21.2. I installed VSCode from the build-in flatpak Software Manager and I encounter the same issue.

First, I think it is quite troublesome to explicitly edit VSCode configuration to access to system SDK.

Secondly, when I turn on Sync, I think the local flatpak VSCode configuration will mess up the online sync-ed version, because VSCode is asking me to merge conflict.

Hence, I rather download VSCode from https://code.visualstudio.com/download and manually install it.

**sudo apt install ./code_(whatever_version).deb**

VSCode installed in this way will work normally.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).